What the garlic is that? (Plant identification help needed)
I planted some fine garlic seeds (I live in Denmark), and while no garlic actually came out - I suspect I overwatered the seeds - this did by some cosmic chance (by wind, or within the soil, or some other way). Any ideas what it might be?


That's the only thing that came out of the seedling cup and I have no idea what it is. It was growing fine, so I decided to re-pot it and see where it goes. It's starting to look a bit like a tree, and if that's the case ought to find it a bigger house pronto. Google Lens identified it as White Birch, but I maintain a skeptical attitude towards that result.
Can that google result actually be correct? I'd be quite surprised to find out I got a tree out of a seedling cup.

Can you please split this up into two separate questions - we do have pretty strict rules about plant id questions and one of them is “one if per question”. Happy to reopen once you have fixed this.

@Stephie Aw, there goes my garlic joke effort. Will do.

Its still too verbose. So I have had to vote not to open. Get rid of flotsam. Show the plant, say you planted garlic and ask what is it. Thats it.

@RohitGupta Done, although begrudgingly. =)

Garlic 'seeds'? Most varieties are sterile, and even if they weren't it would take a long time to grow them to eating size so not really practical... I can say with 100% certainty that that is not garlic, and that the person you got the seeds from was either horribly mistaken or a rip-off artist.

I think it is in birch family. Birch or populus (poplar, aspen) or maybe others. Possibly it was on soil, or with such family, a factor could be the wind.

I just noticed that poplar is not in birch family. I think I confused with Alnus (alder), but it is not an Alnus (in my opinion). Definitely not a monocots (so far from being a garlic).

@SirThinksalot, apologies - in between the edits some information got lost. I am well aware, this did not spring from the garlic seeds, nor is it my assumption that it's garlic. My suspicion is that it came in with the soil or the wind. The garlic seeds simply didn't take (due to overwatering, or weather, or bad luck, or whatever). But I still wanted to know what it is, considering it started to look interesting.

@GiacomoCatenazzi But your thought process is still in the direction of - this is actually a tree sapling? Interesting. I better find it a place to go soon, then.
